# How to get all possible combinations from a list in python allowing repetition

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, combinations, python-itertools

I have a list like `[1,2,3]` and I want to get the following result:

```
1
1,1
1,1,1
1,2
1,2,1
1,2,2
1,2,3
1,2
1,3
1,3,3
2,1,2
2,2,1
3,1,1
etc
```

I've tried using `itertools`, but I only get the combinations without repetition.

Does anyone know how could I get a list with the desired result?

Comment: did you try `itertools.combinations_with_replacement()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick solution by hand. If you care about performance you should probably stick with `itertools`.

```
def all_combs(xs):
    res = []
    buf = [[]]
    lst = [[x] for x in xs]
    for _ in xs:
        buf = [r + l for r in buf for l in lst]
        res.extend(buf)

    return res
```

Answer (score 5):

You need `itertools.combinations_with_replacement()` and vary the `r`. this isn't in your order as it is unclear if this is a requirement, e.g.:

```
In []:
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement as cwr
nums = [1, 2, 3]
[x for n in range(1, len(nums)+1) for x in cwr(nums, r=n)]

Out[]:
[(1,), (2,), (3,), (1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 2), (2, 3), (3, 3), (1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 2), 
 (1, 1, 3), (1, 2, 2), (1, 2, 3), (1, 3, 3), (2, 2, 2), (2, 2, 3), (2, 3, 3), (3, 3, 3)]

In []:
from itertools import product
[x for n in range(1, len(nums)+1) for x in product(nums, repeat=n)]

Out[]:
[(1,), (2,), (3,), (1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3), (3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3), 
 (1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 2), (1, 1, 3), (1, 2, 1), (1, 2, 2), (1, 2, 3), (1, 3, 1), (1, 3, 2), 
 (1, 3, 3), (2, 1, 1), (2, 1, 2), (2, 1, 3), (2, 2, 1), (2, 2, 2), (2, 2, 3), (2, 3, 1), 
 (2, 3, 2), (2, 3, 3), (3, 1, 1), (3, 1, 2), (3, 1, 3), (3, 2, 1), (3, 2, 2), (3, 2, 3), 
 (3, 3, 1), (3, 3, 2), (3, 3, 3)]
```

Comment: Thank you. I made a mistake while asking the question and didnt indicate that also needed combinations like 2,1,1 where the 1st number can be greater than the rest. I don't know if this can be achieved with itertools, but the answer provided by Yakym worked for what I needed.

Comment: Just use `itertools.product()`, added.